# Can I tweak the jQuery datepicker to pick either a full date or a full month or a full year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to build a date picker where the user can select either a day or have options to select a complete month or a complete year. I am planning to use jQuery UI for this.

What I am currently having is, I can select a date using

```
$(function() {$(this).datepicker(); });
```

If I tweak with it, I can build a 'monthpicker' like this :

```
$(function() {var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));});
```

I can also do the same for a complete year. 
Is there someway that I can integrate all three and get something similar to the date picking widget in http://www.skyscanner.com/

Answer (score 0):

There's an API call, showbuttonpanel that allows you to show or hide the panel that has the "today" shortcut.  The logical choice would be to build a custom button on this panel that on click selects the month or year using the datepicker's API functions.

[Here's an example of adding custom buttons in practice.](http://csharptechies.blogspot.com/2010/12/adding-custom-buttons-to-jquery.html)